# IIS program can receive HTTP Requests and Respond, but when it sends a HTTP Request, it cannot read the Response

Tags: c#, http, iis, c#-4.0, iis-7.5

I'm using IIS 7.5 with the 4.0 .NET Framework.
Here is the situation.

The IIS program can receive HTTP requests and respond to them. This is confirmed through debugging. However, when a HTTP request is sent from the IIS program, it throws an exception while trying to read the response. Below is the code I'm using ( it is quite standard ).

```
public static string func( string urlStr )
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string content;
    try
    {
        content = client.DownloadString( urlStr );
    }
    catch( WebException ex )
    {
        /* Handle the exception */
    }

    return content;
}
```

Now, interestingly, I wrote a small c# program to test out this snippet of code. The small standalone c# program works fine. It can send out HTTP requests and receive the responses. The URL's in both cases were identical.

Additionally, using any browser, a browser can get the response using the same URL.

The endpoint of the URL is another program that will respond with a JSON string.
And in the cases of the small c# program and browsers, it does just that.
Only the IIS program throws exceptions while trying to download the string.

Using wireshark, I was able to determine that the URL endpoint is getting the HTTP request and sending the response. However, the response does not make it back to the IIS program.

In all cases, the endpoint was on a different computer.

Below is some information about the exception being thrown.

WebException

- WebException.Message: Unable to connect to the remote server
- WebException.Status: ConnectFailure
- WebException.Response: ( empty )

My question becomes, what could cause this type of behavior?
Are there any configuration properties in IIS that would cause this?

Thank you in advance for your time!

## Edit 1

Exception Callstack:

```
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
```

Comment: If you post the exception that you get in the IIS App, it would be helpful for us to suggest the suitable action.

Comment: Do you have any proxy settings in the web.config of `IIS program`? Can it connect to anything else? Does it have permissions to make network calls?

Comment: please post the exception stacktrace .Does this url you have access has any kind of authentication in place? Also check if you have any proxy settings.By default the proxy used by console application will not be used by IIS as IIS does not run under your identity

Comment: Thank you for replying. I edited the question to include the callstack. The IIS program does not have any proxy settings ( the Web.config does not include those elements). The IIS program does have network permissions. There is no authentification needed.